# Git: Merging a submodule in to a master project

Tags: git, git-submodules

When creating our project, we laid it out like so:

- Applications

  - App...
  - App...
  - Resources (Submodule)

    - JS/CSS/IMG
- Shared System Libraries

  - ...

The idea being that our designer could checkin changes to the Resources submodule without disturbing developers working in the primary repo.

This however has proved to be problematic and cause no end of confusion. Is there anything complex needed to place the Resources folder under control of the master repo? Or is it just the case of duplicating the folder contents minus the Git control files, deleting the original folder and renaming the new one to match the old name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule) for how to remove a submodule in Git. From there, you can just copy the former submodule’s contents into your main repo, and give your designer access to that repo.

If you’re worried about your designer mucking up the main repo (as I would be, being a developer!) then you could also write a simple hook that checks who’s committing, and if they’re attempting to commit any files outside of the resources directory to kill the commit.